# When is PLS_INTEGER actually beneficial for performance?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Looking at examples online, it seems that `pls_integer` is beneficial for arithmetics with other `pls_integer`s only. Is it more performant than number in arithmetics with other data types, such as date?

Running tests like these (Oracle 19.0.0):

```
declare
  i integer;
  v_date_r date;
  v_months /*pls_integer*/ number := 7;
  v_days /*pls_integer*/ number := 98;
begin
  for i in 1..10000000 loop
    v_date_r := add_months(trunc(localtimestamp),-v_months) + v_days;
  end loop;
end;
```

```
declare
  i integer;
  v_date_r date;
  v_days /*pls_integer*/ number := 322;
begin
  for i in 1..10000000 loop
    v_date_r := sysdate + v_days;
  end loop;
end;
```

the tests with pls_integer can often outperform tests with number.

Why?

Isn't pls_integer converted to number to calculate `sysdate + v_days`? My understanding is that it is converted, so how can it be faster?

Since `add_months()` accepts integer, it makes sense that the function would be faster when a pls_integer is passed in rather than number, even though it then also adds `v_days` to the result.

Oracle documentation isn't very clear about this.

Comment: I ran your two tests on 19c and saw virtually no difference between running with NUMBER compared to PLS_INTEGER. You may need to re-run your tests multiple times, alternate running the tests, throw out the outliers, and take an average, to get a true sense of the performance difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sysdate`, `localtimestamp`, `add_months`, etc.. functions will take a *lot* more time calling the OS to get the time or doing complex date manipulations than simple arithmetic operations on numbers, so you can't really test `pls_integer` vs. `number` performance unless you construct a test that eliminates those expensive operations. And passing them `pls_integer` when their argument list expects `number` (unless they have specific overloads for `pls_integer`) won't help as Oracle would immediately convert them implicitly to the datatype expected.

`number` is an artificial datatype constructed on a higher level than a binary integer, and therefore arithmetic on numbers requires more steps in higher-level code than bitwise operations on a binary integer does. But rarely do you have a piece of PL/SQL code that lacks other operations that are astronomically more expensive than these, so rarely does choosing `pls_integer` over `number` make a noticeable difference. You'd have to have something that loops an insane number of times and does nothing but math within it, like this:

```
declare
  j number;
  v_months number := 7;
  v_days number := 98;
  st timestamp with time zone;
begin
  st := systimestamp;
  for i in 1..100000000 loop
    j := GREATEST(i,5+v_months+v_days);
  end loop;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(systimestamp - st);
end;
```

On my system, that resulted in `+000000000 00:00:04.931385000`. Compare `pls_integer`:

```
declare
  j pls_integer;
  v_months pls_integer := 7;
  v_days pls_integer := 98;
  st timestamp with time zone;
begin
  st := systimestamp;
  for i in 1..100000000 loop
    j := GREATEST(i,5+v_months+v_days);
  end loop;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(systimestamp - st);
end;
```

Result: `+000000000 00:00:01.794718000`, just shy of 3x faster. The same can be seen by simply testing the loop iterator itself. Compare:

```
declare
  i number := 0;
  st timestamp with time zone;
begin
  st := systimestamp;
  while i < 100000000 loop
    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(systimestamp - st);
end;       

--> +000000000 00:00:03.044420000

declare
  i pls_integer := 0;
  st timestamp with time zone;
begin
  st := systimestamp;
  while i < 100000000 loop
    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(systimestamp - st);
end;     

--> +000000000 00:00:01.017006000
```

So `pls_integer` is definitely faster for arithmetic operations. But how often will anybody write PL/SQL that does nothing but math in a loop with this many iterations?  And with a hundred million iterations I only saved 2 seconds. It would be a very rare case where it actually made enough of a difference to be worth being too particular about using it over `number`.